# Can I prove that any integer can be written as $2n$ or $2n+1$ using induction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I am used to using induction to prove that a statement is true for all natural numbers.

But with the statement "Any integer can be written as $2n$ or $2n+1$, for some integer $n$", if I define the set A as containing all the integers that satisfy the statement, does the induction below suffice?

$1 = 2 \cdot 0 + 1 \Rightarrow 1 \in A$

Assume $k \in A$,

then $k=2n \: or \: k=2n+1 \Rightarrow k+1 = 2n+1 \: or \: k+1= 2(n+1) = 2m, m \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow k+1 \in A$

Can I conclude that by induction $A=\mathbb{Z}$?

If not what are the missing steps?

Comment: This proves that $A = \mathbb{N}$. You need to tweak your proof a little in order to prove the claim for $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I think I can come up with a verbose way of mapping each natural number to it's additive inverse in a separate proof to show that "Every natural number's additive inverse can be written as 2n or 2n+1". Is this the general strategy when you want to extend a proof to integers, ie these symmetry-type arguments/proofs?

Comment: That's one way.  Another is "backwards" induction.  Prove that it's true for $n=0$ and that if it's true for $n$ then it's true for $n-1$.

Comment: As @RobertIsrael said yes this is a typical strategy. You could also use "backwards" induction if you want a proof only using induction but you're basically doing the same thing over again.